# Can I use hibernate.cfg.xml as a data source for jdbc-user-service?

Tags: spring, spring-security

It seems you can create an authentication manager in xml by using an authentication provider and a jdbc-user-service, which lists a bean as its data source. However, the information in that bean would be more of less the same as the information in hibernate.cfg.xml.

So my question is, do I need to repeat this information, or can I create a data-source-ref to hibernate.cfg.xml?

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="securityDataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?"
                />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security can't read hibernate.cfg.xml, but with some headache you can create `securityDataSource` using Java-based configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        // parse hibernate.cfg.xml, create and return DataSource
    }

}
```

As an alternative approach, you can implement your own `UserDetailsService` that uses Hibernate.